NDIS 6.0 Filter driver does not send ARP reply
I am developing a NDIS filter (NCF_LW_FILTER, FilterClass:Compression, FilterType: Modifying) driver. I am trying to send ARP reply (ethernet header + ARP header) packet to another PC in the same network within a method named 'SendARP()'. The signature of this method is...
    VOID SendARP(
    NDIS_HANDLE         FilterModuleContext,
    PQUEUE_ARP_NODE     pQARPData,
    NDIS_PORT_NUMBER    PortNumber,
    ULONG               SendFlags
    )

In FilterAttach(), I have allocated a NetBufferListPool using NdisAllocateNetBufferListPool().
Inside the SendARP() method, I am allocating a Data buffer of 42 bytes (ethernet header + ARP header) using NdisAllocateMemoryWithTagPriority.
   PVOID pDataBuffer = NdisAllocateMemoryWithTagPriority(pFilter->FilterHandle, 42, 
   FILTER_ALLOC_TAG, NormalPoolPriority).

In this data buffer (pDataBuffer), I am copying the required ethernet header (14 bytes) + ARP Header (28 bytes). After copying (in network byte order) the ethernet and ARP header in the allocated buffer, I am allocating an MDL specifying the pDataBuffer buffer.
    PMDL pmdl = NdisAllocateMdl(pFilter->FilterHandle, pDataBuffer, 42);

After allocating the MDL, I am allocating the NET_BUFFER and NET_BUFFER_LIST specifying the MDL.
    PNET_BUFFER_LIST pnbl = NdisAllocateNetBufferAndNetBufferList(pFilter->NetBufferListPool, 0, 0, pmdl, 0, 42);

Now, I assigned the filter handle to the sourceHandle of the NET_BUFFER_LIST
    pnbl->SourceHandle = pFilter->FilterHandle;

And finally send the packet
NdisFSendNetBufferLists(pFilter->FilterHandle, pnbl, PortNumber, SendFlags);
The filter FilterSendNetBufferLists() method looks like below,
    VOID FilterSendNetBufferLists(
          NDIS_HANDLE         FilterModuleContext,
          PNET_BUFFER_LIST    NetBufferLists,
          NDIS_PORT_NUMBER    PortNumber,
          ULONG               SendFlags
        )
        {
            PMS_FILTER          pFilter       = (PMS_FILTER)FilterModuleContext;
            FILTER_STATE        fState        = FilterStateUnspecified;
            BOOLEAN             DispatchLevel = FALSE;
            BOOLEAN             bFalse        = FALSE;

            FILTER_ACQUIRE_LOCK(&pFilter->Lock, DispatchLevel);
            fState = pFilter->State;
            FILTER_RELEASE_LOCK(&pFilter->Lock, DispatchLevel);

            if (fState == FilterRunning)
            {
                SendARP(FilterModuleContext, pARPData, PortNumber, SendFlags);
                
                //Original NET_BUFFER_LIST
                NdisFSendNetBufferLists(pFilter->FilterHandle, NetBufferLists, 
                PortNumber, SendFlags);
            }
            else
            {
                NdisFSendNetBufferListsComplete(pFilter->FilterHandle, NetBufferLists, 
                SendFlags);
            }
         }

The driver is installed on a VM (Win 10) connected by a virtual switch.
The problem is that the ARP reply packet is not delivering. Looks like it is discarding for any reason. I installed Wireshark in the VM, where I did not see that the ARP packet is going out.
The FilterSendNetBufferListsComplete() is defined in the following way...
    FilterSendNetBufferListsComplete(
    NDIS_HANDLE         FilterModuleContext,
    PNET_BUFFER_LIST    NetBufferLists,
    ULONG               SendCompleteFlags
    )
    {
         if (pFilter->FilterHandle == NetBufferLists->SourceHandle)
         {
              NdisFreeNetBufferList(NetBufferLists);
         }
         else
         {
              NdisFSendNetBufferListsComplete(pFilter->FilterHandle, NetBufferLists, 
              SendCompleteFlags);
         }
     }

Can anyone please suggest what is the wrong with the above code?
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Use !ndiskd.nbl in windbg to verify you've created the NBL correctly. It can print the data payload, and export that to a .cap file you can look at in wireshark to verify the ARP header looks correct. Don't pass SendFlags to NdisFSendNetBufferListsComplete. It's unlikely that the SendFlags from an unrelated NBL will apply to your new ARP; just create new SendFlags of 0 for new NBLs. Your FilterSendNetBufferListsComplete needs to loop over all the NBLs in the chain. NdisClassifyNblChainBySourceHandle can help with this.

Thanks a lot, Now the filter driver is working, But I am facing a problem. When I am calling SendARP function (which actually sends the ARP buffer) from PASSIVE LEVEL, it is working and the driver is unloading without any issue. When I am calling from SendNetBufferListsHandler method, it is working, but driver hangs on NdisFDeregisterFilterDriver of FilterUnload (). So, FilterDetach is not calling. I tried to cancel the pending NET_BUFFER_LIST with cancel id but did not work. Noticed, when NdisFDeregisterFilterDriver hangs, FilterSendNetBufferLists is still calling continuously by Ndis.

Try looking in kd with !stacks 2 ndis! to see what it's waiting on. Make sure you don't leak NBLs. Canceling NBLs is rarely implemented by drivers, so don't worry about trying it.
